# Gmail: Can no longer find emails from one sender

Tags: gmail

You used to be able to find all messages to/from a Gmail sender by hovering the cursor over the sender's name. Can no longer do that with the "New Look." Is there an easy solution other than doing a search and typing in the name?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to click Settings, then click Send Feedback and send your request/complaint to Google like I did. When enough people ask for it, they'll bring that feature back.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on gear icon (settings) to go back to earlier look and feel of Gmail
"Go back to Classic Gmail"

Or you can select an email and use the 3 dots menu on top to use the option
"Filter messages like these" and then clicking Search button